# Handling a multiple page JSON and TableView?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, api, alamofire

I want to import a list of exercises into a tableview. I have it working to import the first page, however this is only a handful of exercises. The JSON seems to have 'next page' links, and I want to be able to load them all when i start the loading process.

Would i need to use some sort of if else statement to load consecutive pages if they exist otherwise end loading?

This is my API service

```
open class ApiService: NSObject {

open func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {

    let requestUrl = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json"

    Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success( let data):

                completionHandler(data as? NSDictionary, nil)

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
            }
    }
    return self
}
```

}

This is my JSON, which clearly references the following page in its first line

> https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json

This is my tableview pulling the data in if relevant

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    if (searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        if let row: NSDictionary = arrRes[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary? {

            guard let name = row["name"] as? String else {
                print("Fail")
                return cell
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = name
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Thanks for some advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could load the next page of exercises in the background, and then add them to the result array (`arrRes` in your case) when the request completes.

Then, when you call
`tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` with the indexes of the new results, the table view should animate the new results in.

Comment: Sounds good, but i have no idea how to do this which was the initial question

Answer (score 0):

The same way you did here to get the name property from the json file

```
guard let name = row["name"] as? String else {
    print("Fail")
    return cell
}
```

Wherever you want to load the next page do something like

```
// data is the json result you have from the first request
func lookForNextPage(data: NSDictionary, completionHandler: @escaping (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    // Try and see if a next page exist
    if let nextPage = data["next"] as? String {
        // There is a next page, fetch it and add result to datasource
        Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( let data):
                    // Handle the new data as you wish
                    completionHandler(data as? NSDictionary, nil)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, just adapt it to your needs